# Heroku Executable Jar App Crashing After a Few Seconds

Tags: java, heroku, executable-jar

I'm attempting to run a Java Discord bot which I've compiled into an executable jar on Heroku. When running this jar on my machine, it runs continuously without crashing.
As per [the Heroku instructions for deploying an executable jar via CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-executable-jar-files#using-the-heroku-java-cli-plugin), I've run the command line commands:

```
heroku plugins:install java
heroku create storytelling-bot --no-remote --region eu
heroku deploy:jar StoryTellerBot.jar --app storytelling-bot
```

The last of these commands seems to throw several Java exceptions, but as far as I can tell these are not related to my .jar and seem like they're a cleanup process of temporary files the deploy process creates on my machine not having access for whatever reason:

```
remote:        https://storytelling-bot.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
-----> Done
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to delete C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\heroku-deploy3868081789627054304
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.DeleteDirectoryRunnable.run(DeleteDirectoryRunnable.java:46)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\heroku-deploy3868081789627054304\heroku\app\.heroku-deploy: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Unknown Source)
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.DeleteDirectoryRunnable$1.visitFile(DeleteDirectoryRunnable.java:21)
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.DeleteDirectoryRunnable$1.visitFile(DeleteDirectoryRunnable.java:16)
        at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Unknown Source)
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.DeleteDirectoryRunnable.run(DeleteDirectoryRunnable.java:44)
        ... 1 more
```

Despite the exception the jar runs on Heroku for a little longer than a minute. After the minute is up, the app stops running. The complete Heroku log, from running

```
heroku logs --tail -a storytelling-bot
```

says:

```
2020-05-09T22:16:05.389817+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user {my email}
2020-05-09T22:16:05.389817+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user {my email}
2020-05-09T22:16:05.695884+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user {my email}
2020-05-09T22:16:05.695884+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user {my email}
2020-05-09T22:21:29.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user {my email}
2020-05-09T22:21:41.843885+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user {my email}
2020-05-09T22:21:41.824208+00:00 app[api]: Deploy by user {my email}
2020-05-09T22:21:41.824208+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user {my email}
2020-05-09T22:21:42.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-05-09T22:21:47.570594+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2020-05-09T22:21:47.574241+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2020-05-09T22:21:47.802707+00:00 app[web.1]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
2020-05-09T22:21:47.802709+00:00 app[web.1]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
2020-05-09T22:21:47.802709+00:00 app[web.1]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
2020-05-09T22:21:48.770049+00:00 app[web.1]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder".
2020-05-09T22:21:48.770213+00:00 app[web.1]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation MDCAdapter implementation.
2020-05-09T22:21:48.770431+00:00 app[web.1]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#no_static_mdc_binder for further details.
2020-05-09T22:21:48.934598+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] INFO JDA - Login Successful!
2020-05-09T22:21:49.283574+00:00 app[web.1]: [JDA MainWS-ReadThread] INFO WebSocketClient - Connected to WebSocket
2020-05-09T22:21:49.547755+00:00 app[web.1]: [JDA MainWS-ReadThread] INFO JDA - Finished Loading!
2020-05-09T22:23:16.058897+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-09T22:23:16.132636+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-09T22:23:20.713652+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2020-05-09T22:23:20.717823+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2020-05-09T22:23:20.997244+00:00 app[web.1]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
2020-05-09T22:23:20.997305+00:00 app[web.1]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
2020-05-09T22:23:20.997385+00:00 app[web.1]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
2020-05-09T22:23:21.975791+00:00 app[web.1]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder".
2020-05-09T22:23:21.975824+00:00 app[web.1]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation MDCAdapter implementation.
2020-05-09T22:23:21.975921+00:00 app[web.1]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#no_static_mdc_binder for further details.
2020-05-09T22:23:22.118150+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] INFO JDA - Login Successful!
2020-05-09T22:23:22.462633+00:00 app[web.1]: [JDA MainWS-ReadThread] INFO WebSocketClient - Connected to WebSocket
2020-05-09T22:23:22.720617+00:00 app[web.1]: [JDA MainWS-ReadThread] INFO JDA - Finished Loading!
2020-05-09T22:24:49.394239+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

As the log states, the application stops running. (Note that the "failed to load class" lines are consistent with what I get when running the application on my machine; they do not cause the application to terminate.)

Why is the Jar crashing like this? Presumably either my Jar or my Heroku application needs some additional setup to work correctly - although this is not mentioned as part of Heroku's guide to setting up an Executable Jar via CLI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given not much info what you are actually doing in your app, so I‘m guessing.

Could it be that you are not binding to the web port and use a webworker?

From the docs

> Web dynos
>   A web dyno must bind to its assigned $PORT within 60 seconds of startup. If it doesn’t, it is terminated by the dyno manager and a R10 Boot Timeout error is logged. Processes can bind to other ports before and after binding to $PORT.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#web-dynos